# AWS Batch / AWS container Memory Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I currently have an application which I am trying to run using AWS batch. The app runs fine when locally running on my laptop.

`docker run myapp`

But the same app running in AWS batch keeps getting memory error even when providing  128GB of memory.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe its host memory and not container memory that is running out? Can you post the actual error message? Try running on an instance with more memory?

Comment: I started from 16GB -> 32 -> 64 and 128GB .. Same memory error all the way. Since its aws batch I don't have much control on the host memory. I am guessing AWS batch would take care of that when allocation the container.

Comment: you do get to choose instance type when you create a batch compute environment. Choose a higher instance type to give the host more memory.

Comment: What does it run? Is it a Java application?